# Cannot upvote or comment

Tags: support, bug, stack-overflow

I am unable use the options like comment,flag,share,delete for my question but I can edit and also I cannot use upvote, like, comment for the answers I have got.
**I have enabled javascript on my browser**

Even I have tried with different browsers still the problem persists.

Due to this my acceptance % is decreasing.

What might be the actual reason for this?

And also I have enough reputation score to upvote the question (110 at SO now).

Here I am giving reply to jmort because I can't add comment over there.

1. I am trying to upvote the answer for my question .
2. When I click on add comment,upvote or like nothing happens even I don't get any message

I am using firefox 16.0.1 and Google chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m

Comment: Are you trying to upvote your own question or the answers to the question, or other questions? What makes you think your acceptance rate is decreasing due to voting or commenting? What happens when you try to leave a comment on your question?

Comment: Odd. What browsers (including versions) did you try using?

Comment: ISP blocking AJAX?

Comment: I had a similar issue myself but it was due to a tampermonkey script: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339957/most-of-the-links-in-stackexchange-sites-go-nowhere-when-using-chrome
Check if any scripts or browser plugins you have installed on both browsers may cause this.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in a comment to [your now deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151340/152859) on your first report, something external might be blocking JavaScript on your machine. Things to consider:

1. Try to disable any Anti Virus or Security program you have just for sake of seeing if this resolve your issue with JavaScript.
2. If you are in a corporate network the block might be out of your control, so try browsing from home and see if it works.

Answer (score -2):

The actions you describe require minimum reputation score (see [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)). You seem to be a new user. Hang around for a while.

Welcome :)

Comment: True, but quick check can reveal he's well above 100 already. (in the main site)